# Fail to use unicode character "per ten thousand" as axis label

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

I would like to add the "per ten thousand" symbol to an axis label with `ggplot2`.

To insert the "per thousand" symbol I can use :

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1, 1) + ylab("\u2030")
```

But when I use

```
qplot(1, 1) + ylab("\u2031")
```

to generate the "per ten thousand" symbol, the output generated is a box containing a question mark. The text family used is Calibri, however the same output is generated with the default text family.

Is this symbol supported?

Comment: Pascal, yes the above results in the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a font that supports this symbol. From [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2031/fontsupport.htm) I tried `Arial Unicode MS`:

```
windowsFonts(
  A=windowsFont("Arial Unicode MS")
)
plot(1)
text(1, 1.2,"\u2031", family = "A")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Consult [this tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/) for changing fonts in ggplot2.

Comment: Is there a unicode symbol "per billion"?  I use lawyers per billion all the time, for example.

Comment: @lawyeR I don't think so. In chemistry you have ppb = parts per billion. So maybe define lpb?