# Special characters in R plots

Tags: r, plot

I have a code in which I use

```
plot(1, 1, type="s", ylab="log ℓ")
```

that is equivalent to

```
plot(1, 1, type="s", ylab="log \u2113")
```

produces a nice slanted `l` representing likelihood in the `y-axis`.

Why the capital script version of `l (\u2112)` gives me only a box in place of the L?

I'm running R on a Mac.

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux in a clean R session. What font are you using? Do you use any other packages that modify what fonts are used in the graphics device?

Comment: +1 for the font thing. If you do a simple `print("\U2112")` it works fine in console, i.e. the character is correctly recognized.

Comment: Seems related to [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056473/fail-to-use-unicode-character-per-ten-thousand-as-axis-label).

Comment: Thanks, koekenbakker, I got it. I downloaded a new font "Paramount Mountain v2", which has the fancy "L" and it worked. Bad thing is that the "log" in front of the "L" is slanted too.
But I think it is ok.